# Editing Calc formula, when clicking cell, it does not enter cell reference

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, editing

When I am writing a formula, I can type =A1+A2 and it works, but if I type = and then click on A1, the system does not put A1 in the formula bar.  It just enters A1 in edit mode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could not reproduce — I tried it just now and it worked fine, even if I clicked first in the formula bar or the edited cell. Please specify version and OS. Is it possible that  some other software is running such as an AutoHotkey script? Test with a new spreadsheet, and maybe restart the computer.

Comment: I found that the calculated cell was text.  Once I turned it to a number field, it was OK.  What is it with the blue triangle in the lower left of the cell?